# Эффективное сглаживание массива numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Есть массив numpy, например:

```
`array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
`
```

Какой наиболее эффективный и быстрый способ его сгладить, чтобы каждому элементу назначался некоторый коэффициент в промежутке [0,1], в зависимости от удаленности элемента от ближайшей единицы (позиции единиц известны). То есть, получиться должно примерно так:

```
`array([[0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7],
       [0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8],
       [0.9, 1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9],
       [0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8],
       [0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7]])
`
```

Написал свой алгоритм на чистом питоне, но на большом объеме очень медленно работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гаусовский фильтр позволяет сглаживать картинки:

```
In [89]: a
Out[89]:
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

In [90]: from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

In [91]: gaussian_filter(a, sigma=(.8,.8), mode='nearest')
Out[91]:
array([[0.00501202, 0.01140622, 0.01000472, 0.01140622, 0.00501202],
       [0.05222641, 0.11885554, 0.10425157, 0.11885554, 0.05222641],
       [0.11407297, 0.25960436, 0.22770636, 0.25960436, 0.11407297],
       [0.05222641, 0.11885554, 0.10425157, 0.11885554, 0.05222641],
       [0.00501202, 0.01140622, 0.01000472, 0.01140622, 0.00501202]])
```

Исходный массив:

```
In [92]: plt.imshow(a, cmap='Blues')
Out[92]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x23cb2ec3390>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сглаженный:

```
In [94]: plt.imshow(gaussian_filter(a, sigma=(.8,.8)), cmap='Blues')
Out[94]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x23cb7e7b9e8>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> А можно как-то чтоб единицы сохранились?

```
In [113]: r = gaussian_filter(a, sigma=.8)

In [114]: r
Out[114]:
array([[0.00560256, 0.01164552, 0.01020597, 0.01164552, 0.00560256],
       [0.05722877, 0.11895616, 0.10425157, 0.11895616, 0.05722877],
       [0.12499912, 0.25982415, 0.22770636, 0.25982415, 0.12499912],
       [0.05722877, 0.11895616, 0.10425157, 0.11895616, 0.05722877],
       [0.00560256, 0.01164552, 0.01020597, 0.01164552, 0.00560256]])

In [115]: r[a==1] = 1

In [116]: r
Out[116]:
array([[0.00560256, 0.01164552, 0.01020597, 0.01164552, 0.00560256],
       [0.05722877, 0.11895616, 0.10425157, 0.11895616, 0.05722877],
       [0.12499912, 1.        , 0.22770636, 1.        , 0.12499912],
       [0.05722877, 0.11895616, 0.10425157, 0.11895616, 0.05722877],
       [0.00560256, 0.01164552, 0.01020597, 0.01164552, 0.00560256]])
```

Comment: спасибо, это хорошо. 
А можно как-то чтоб единицы сохранились? пересчитать вручную, конечно, можно, а через аргуенты фильтра?